# On-prem nuget package is available but appears empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuspec

I have created a dotnet core 3.0 shared library for internal usage across projects, I've set up nuget packaging and publishing.

The nupkg file is available in the nuget feed and discoverable:

[image]

That `v0.1.0-rc-logging0006` version is the correct one. It's the most recent version.

The reference is correctly linked in the solution:

[image]

Yet, it appears my package is completely empty.

I've created a test class:

```
namespace tbn.shared.utility.Logging
{
    public class Testing
    {
        public bool IAmTesting => true;
    }
}
```

Although public, it's not discoverable. Adding the namespace to the *using* list doesn't work either.

I'm referencing my package from a console app (also dotnet core 3.0), if I add the name `Testing` and resolve the reference, that fails. I only get *generate class* options.

**Nuspec**

I'm currently using this nuspec definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>tbn.shared.utility</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <authors>Company</authors>
    <owners>Company</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>my tags</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

**Question**

> What could be the reason my package appears to be empty while it isn't
>   and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you rename the file to `.zip` and examine its contents?

Comment: @mjwills: I have, looks exactly the way I'd expect.There is a folder Logging with a Testing.cs, with the expected code. So looks good ...

Comment: Usually nuget packages contain .dll files not .cs files.
Easiest way to do this is by generating package from project instead of entirely by hand
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-visual-studio-project

Comment: @user3455363: So perhaps the packaging process doesn't exactly run like it should. I'll look into it.

Comment: See my answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: For SDK style projects (all .NET Core/Standard projects are SDK style) don't create a nuspec, and just use `dotnet pack`, it auto-generates a nuspec from the project and packs things correctly. All metadata you normally have in your nuspec, you [put in your csproj as MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target).

Comment: @zivkan: I did notice that, but then I'm not in control of what is used for authorship information. Good to know though!

Comment: If u r interested in Source Code nugets - which is rarely done (as per @user3455363 comment), but I think should be done more...  https://github.com/shaynevanasperen/Code and earlier version https://github.com/shaynevanasperen/Quarks to pint in right  direction, I have a version of this for lots of library code... my current setup is slow to build the packages... but worth it... so handy, particularly awesome is the mapping of dependencies. like npm for c# (etc)

Comment: Even when slow - sooooo worth it... super handy, and neat, particularly awesome is the mapping of dependencies, also having the code "injected" into consumer (~like npm for c# etc) + ability to step thru is mega! Goodbye to Shared.csproj or library/just feeing dirty when u put things in the wrong place just to keep compiler happy and not add another proj to a big sln. so worth checking out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following to the nuspec:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\netcoreapp3.0\tbn.shared.utility.dll" target="lib" >
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\netcoreapp3.0\tbn.shared.utility.pdb" target="lib" />
</files>
```

---

As a whole that gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>tbn.shared.utility</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <authors>Company</authors>
        <owners>Company</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>My description</description>
        <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
        <tags>my tags</tags>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\$configuration$\netcoreapp3.0\tbn.shared.utility.dll" target="lib" />
        <file src="bin\$configuration$\netcoreapp3.0\tbn.shared.utility.pdb" target="lib" />
    </files>
</package>
```